# I am looking for the title of a science fiction anthology that contains stories about food

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, food

The only thing that I can remember about this anthology of science fiction stories that were about food is that one of the stories was about a creature similar to a lobster called a "malaprop" that did not want to be cooked.

Comment: Do you remember when you read this? A year ago? Ten years ago? Decades ago?

Comment: I don't imagine there's many creatures (apart from in Hitchhiker's Guide) that actually want to be cooked

Answer (score 5):

The story you are describing could be [*Rabid in Mallworld*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43405) by S. P. Somtow. It contains a lobster like animal that is called a malaprop.

> "First there’s the alien gourmet cooking. Courtesy of our Selespridon masters’ trade routes, there’s softshell malaprops marinated
> in angels’ tears, roast Vegan dingwort, klitterbungas fried in oyster
> sauce, sweet-and-sour ice turtles with chocolate chips, as well as
> ancient earth dishes, whose recipes are extracted — by the restaurant’s research department — from ancient, decaying earth documents (so the propaganda goes): bird’s nest soup, roast boar, London
> broil, corned beef hash.

It has been repeatedly collected, but I can't find an anthology that is exclusively about food.